# How drop a target from a label in prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I'm trying to do somethings quite easy, I think, but I don't find how do that :D

So I use the backbox exporter to do some HTTP checks and my list of host is stored in files.

I want to do my HTTP check on targets were labels `feature=web` (because others hosts doesn't respond on HTTP :D ).

But I don't find how do that.

So my config

```
  - job_name: blackbox_http
    metrics_path: /probe
    params:
      module: [http_2xx]
    static_configs:
    - targets: 
    file_sd_configs:
      - files:
        - hosts/*.json

    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: __param_target
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        target_label: instance
      - target_label: __address__
        replacement: localhost:9115
```

And a sample of my hosts.json files

```
[
    {
        "targets": [
            "serv1",
            "serv2"
        ],
        "labels": {
            "feature": "web"
        }
    },
    {
        "targets": [
            "serv3"
        ],
        "labels": {
            "feature": "db"
        }
    }
]
```

I thinks I need to do a `action: drop` on `relabel_configs` but I don't know how do that on label.
So do you have any ideas ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found it

```
      - source_labels: [feature]
        regex: 'web'
        action: keep
```